# Shotwell fatal error

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I'm looking for any help anyone might be able to offer on the following crash message in Shotwell:

> Shotwell A fatal error occurred when accessing Shotwell's library. 
>   Shotwell cannot continue.
>
> (DatabaseTable.update_text_by_id_2 PhotoTable.filename) [11] -
>   database disk image is malformed

This was following a system crash following some issues upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I'm looking for a way to restore the tags to my thousands of photos for my small bookbinding business. But just being able to start Shotwell would be great too.

I have found that moving all the photos away from the Pictures folder sometimes temporarily allows me to start Shotwell, but the application crashes if any older photos (i.e., not recently uploaded) are in the Pictures folder.

Comment: Can you reload the Shotwell database from a backup? It's in `/home/[username]/.local/share/shotwell` I've been able to copy this directory to a different pc and have it pick up all the tags from my photo lib on a common server. I have about 50K photos and this database is about 45 megabytes (not all the photos are tagged).

Comment: I did find the file you're referring to, but I'm not sure how to reload it. Obviously, a power user I am not, unfortunately. 

I did try to go to the Shotwell Missing Files tab, after looking into this matter further. I tried to remove the missing files, but that prompted Shotwell to shut down again, with the following:
(PhotoTable.remove) [11] - database disk image is malformed

Is there some way to clear Shotwell's cache, would that resolve this?

Comment: If you have a backup, you could just copy the directory I listed above from the backup into your machine.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but I had the same problem (running Fedora). The suggestion in one of the comments was dead on. I copied `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db.bak` to `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db` and every thing worked again.